# Multiple props type, Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Sorry I don't know exactly how to name this post.

Using react and typescript :
I have a component that create a set a component based on a type I pass as props :

```
interface FieldDispatcherProps {
  children: Array<never>;
  fieldId: string;
  mandatory?: boolean;
  mode: FieldMode;
  onChange: Function;
}

const fieldTypes = {
  [FieldsHelper.fields.text.value] : TextField,
  [FieldsHelper.fields.textarea.value] : TextAreaField,
  [FieldsHelper.fields.select.value] : SelectField,
  [FieldsHelper.fields.radio.value] : RadioField,
  [FieldsHelper.fields.checkbox.value] : CheckboxField,
  [FieldsHelper.fields.autonum.value] : AutonumField,
  [FieldsHelper.fields.number.value] : NumberField,
  [FieldsHelper.fields.file.value] : FileField,
  [FieldsHelper.fields.calc.value] : CalcField,
  [FieldsHelper.fields.user.value] : UserField,
  [FieldsHelper.fields.dslookup.value] : LookupField,
  [FieldsHelper.fields.date.value] : DateField,
  [FieldsHelper.fields.time.value] : TimeField,
}

const FieldDispatcher = (props: FieldDispatcherProps): JSX.Element => {
  const {fieldId, mandatory, mode, onChange}: FieldDispatcherProps = props;
  const field = useSelector((state: RootState) => ItemDetailsSelectors.getFieldById(state))(fieldId);
  const value = useSelector((state: RootState) => ItemDetailsSelectors.getEntryValue(state))(fieldId);
  return (
    <div>
      {((): JSX.Element  => {
        const FieldType = fieldTypes[field.dataType];
        if(FieldType) {
          return <FieldType onChange={onChange} mode={mode} mandatory={mandatory} field={field} value={value} fieldId={fieldId}/>
        } else {
          return <div>{value}</div>;
        }
      })()}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Now, Every field as the same props name, but, the prop named `value` is of a different type in each component. Some expect an array, other a string, other num....

The problem I face is

```
        const FieldType = fieldTypes[field.dataType];
        if(FieldType) {
          return <FieldType onChange={onChange} mode={mode} mandatory={mandatory} field={field} value={value} fieldId={fieldId}/>
        } else {
          return <div>{value}</div>;
        }
```

Return the following error for the props value:

> Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'.

If I set all my child to expect a value of type any it works, but I would like to keep the child type.

IS there a way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how to give a concrete answer here, as you are using a bunch of unknown helpers and types in your sample code. In general two alternatives come to my mind to handle `value` typing:

1.) Annotate a base type to `fieldTypes`, which declares`value` as `any`:

```
type BaseProps<T> = {
  value: T;
};

const TextField = (p: BaseProps<string>) => <span>{p.value}</span>;
const RadioField = (p: BaseProps<boolean>) => <span>{p.value}</span>;

const fieldTypes: { [K: string]: (props: BaseProps<any>) => JSX.Element } = {
  a: TextField,
  b: RadioField
};
```

So you don't need to change the child component type to expect `value` of type `any`, just change the `fieldTypes` mapping type. Doesn't matter, what `value` you retrieve by `useSelector(..)`, it will fit to `any`.

2.) Narrow exact `value` type down via type guards/control flow:

```
const FieldDispatcher = (props: FieldDispatcherProps) => {
  const value = useSelector( .. ) // value comes from somewhere
  // field.dataType comes from somewhere 
  // lets assume, fieldTypes looks like {"a" : TextField , "b" : CheckboxField}
  const dataType: keyof typeof fieldTypes = ...  

  let fieldTypeJsx: JSX.Element;
  switch (dataType) {
    case "a": {
      // dataType narrowed to "a" here, so fieldTypes[dataType]
      // contains the specific Field Comp
      const FieldType = fieldTypes[dataType];
      // depends on value type, if you have to type cast here
      fieldTypeJsx = <FieldType value={value as string} />;
      break;
    }
    case "b": {
      // analogue to case "a"
      const FieldType = fieldTypes[dataType];
      fieldTypeJsx = <FieldType value={value as boolean} />;
      break;
    }
    default: {
      return <div>{value}</div>;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you declare the type of `children` to be `Array<never>`, so when you pass children, since at least one of the children is not of type `never`, the array of children is an array of type `any`, and [according to the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#never):

> [...] *no* type is a subtype of, or assignable to, `never` (except `never` itself). Even `any` isn’t assignable to `never`.

So changing `children` to be of type `Array<any>` (or something more specific) will solve this problem.

However, you mention that you would like to keep the type of children. An array of type `never` seems a strange type for the `children` array, and another type (like `Array<any>`) seems more appropriate. Alternatively, if you really need to keep children as `Array<never>`, perhaps this prop should not be `children`, but another prop instead.

Comment: the children is not the problem, The problem is the prop on child that are different https://prnt.sc/pw99gs But I can't find a way to make the compiler understand that the props are correct

Comment: @Bobby so the issue is that the `value` prop of the component `FieldType` has a prop type of `never`, but when passed in, the value is of type `any`?